# How to count the weeks between specific week numbers?

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I Have the below data format.It is a dictionary with names as keys, and a list of week numbers as values.

```
{'Mali': [17, 16, 23, 18, 17, 16, 17, 18, 16],
 'Gooki': [7, 8, 8, 15, 7, 7, 8],
 'Piata': [85],     
 'Goerge': [82],
 'Samoo': [106, 55],
 'Marria: [101,39]}
```

I would like to count the number of weeks between the week numbers, and change the value of dictionary with the number of weeks instead of week numbers.This means that for instance in name 'Samoo' I have week 55 and week 106. I would like my code to count these two weeks plus the weeks between them(which is equal to 52 weeks ) and set it as the value for dictionary.

I have the below code, but I am not sure to make this above count.

```
datedict = defaultdict(set)
with open('d:/info.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, 'excel')

    #passing the header
    read_header = False
    start_date=date(year=2009,month=1,day=1)
    #print((seen_date - start_date).days)
    tdict = {}
    for row in filereader: 
        if not read_header:
            read_header = True
            continue

# reading the rest rows
        name,firstseen = row[0],row[3]
        try:
            seen_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(firstseen, '%d/%m/%Y').date()               
            deltadays = (seen_date-start_date).days
            deltaweeks = deltadays/7 + 1
            key = name
            currentvalue = tdict.get(key, set())
            currentvalue.add(deltaweeks)
            tdict[key] = currentvalue

        except ValueError:
            print('Date value error')
            pass

pprint.pprint(tdict)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You have `Samoo` twice in your dictionary. Is this intended? Also, isn't `106-55` equal to `51`? Sorry, I may be misunderstanding your question

Comment: @Haidro I think he wants to count the 106th week as well so that would just be `+1`

Comment: @jamylak Ah that seems reasonable. Actually, I think you are correct. Look at this line: `deltaweeks = deltadays/7 + 1`

Comment: Could you please give the answer for: `'Mali'`

Comment: Mali has between 16 and 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'Mali': [17, 16, 23, 18, 17, 16, 17, 18, 16],
 'Gooki': [7, 8, 8, 15, 7, 7, 8],
 'Piata': [85],
 'Samoo': [47, 63, 48, 58, 49, 48],
 'Goerge': [82],
 'Samoo': [106, 55],
 'Marria': [101,39]}
>>> dict((name, max(weeks) - min(weeks) + 1) for name, weeks in d.iteritems())
{'Samoo': 52, 'Gooki': 9, 'Mali': 8, 'Goerge': 1, 'Piata': 1, 'Marria': 63}
```

Comment: @user2058811 `dict` isn't a variable, it's a function. Also you didn't post the error

Comment: @user2058811 You must have called one of your variables `dict` which shadowed the builtin, check your code for any variables called `dict` and change their name. This snippet: `dict = __builtins__.dict` should reset it for you

Comment: @user2058811 Like this: `>>> dict`
`<type 'dict'>`, that's fine

Comment: @user2058811 Yes that's supposed to happen, it's a function (it prints `type` because it was made in C). Now try running the code: `dict((name, max(weeks) - min(weeks) + 1) for name, weeks in d.iteritems())`